# Bootstrap DatePicker Splitting Date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm in the process of updating an old booking systems views and I am presently stuck on a solution for updating the calendar widget. As the site is responsive I have opted for the bootstrap datepicker supplied by eternicode https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker.

OK here the issue. I have an old Datepicker that splits the checkin & checkout dates into 3 parts and then formats the date for PHP (n = Month no leading zero)) (j = Day no leading zero) & (Y = Year 4 digit numeric).

```
// Initiate Params
   $checkInDate = mktime(0,0,0,date("n"),date("j") + 1,date("Y"));
   $checkOutDate = mktime(0,0,0,date("n"),date("j") + 3,date("Y"));   
//CheckInDate
   if (!isset($daysI)){
      $daysI = date("j",$checkInDate);
   }
   if (!isset($monthsI)){
      $monthsI = date("n",$checkInDate);
   }
   if (!isset($yearI)){
      $yearI = date("Y",$checkInDate);
   }
//CheckOutDate
   if (!isset($daysS)){
      $daysS = date("j",$checkOutDate);
   }
   if (!isset($monthsS)){
      $monthsS = date("n",$checkOutDate);
   }
   if (!isset($yearS)){
      $yearS = date("Y",$checkOutDate);
   }
```

The input boxes markup is as below.

```
<input type='text' id='fulldate' name='fulldate'>
<label>Enter Day of Arrival (in the format DD) </label>
<input type="text" name="daysI" id="daysI" size="6" maxlength="6" /> 
<label>Enter Month of Arrival (in the format MM) </label>
<input type="text" name="monthsI" id="monthsI" size="6" maxlength="6" /> 
<label>Enter Year of Arrival (in the format YYYY) </label>
<input type="text" name="yearI" id="yearI" size="6" maxlength="6" />
```

Here's where I'm having the problem. The following function works with jQuery UI:

```
$('#fulldate').datepicker({
    showAnim: 'fadeIn',
    dateFormat: 'd/m/yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var pieces = dateText.split('/');
        $('#daysI').val(pieces[0]);
        $('#daysI').val(pieces[1]);
        $('#daysI').val(pieces[2]);
    }
});
```

However I cannot get a similar solution to work with the bootstrap-datepicker which I am using as a replacement for jQuery UI ie:

```
$('#fulldate').datepicker({
    format: "d/m/yyyy",
    todayBtn: "linked",
    todayHighlight: true
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var pieces = dateText.split('/');
        $('#daysI').val(pieces[0]);
        $('#monthsI').val(pieces[1]);
        $('#yearI').val(pieces[2]);
    }
});
```

Thank in advance for any solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation gives an example of how to capture the date changed event: [bootstrap-datepicker Docs - Change Date Event](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/events.html#changedate)

Something like this should be in the right direction (untested):

```
$('#fulldate').datepicker()
.on('changeDate', function(ev){

  var newDate = new Date(ev.date);

   $('#daysI').val(newDate.getDate());
   $('#monthsI').val(newDate.getMonth());
   $('#yearI').val(newDate.getFullYear());

});
```

Comment: In general I like to use Unixtime when dealing with dates in PHP, it makes storage, calculations and formatting easier.

Comment: Hi, The object of using the datepicker is to present the user with one way to enter the date. The split fields will be hidden and only used to pass the correct data to the php variables.

Comment: To give you an understanding I am working with a legacy booking system that is icon cubed so have no access to the codebase. What i am trying to do is fully strip back the front end pages to make them responsive as they have been built with table inside table so unfortunately all the work has to be in the format I have been supplied with. ie split and pass.